# Character to appear anywhere in the string?

Tags: regex

I would like to create a RegEx that follows these rules:

- Pattern starts with the letter K
- Is followed by any number (0-9) or any letter (a-z) between 1 and 3 times.
- The symbol # can exist 0 or 1 time, anywhere after the starting K.
- The pattern must end with the symbol $.

I'm confused on the 3rd rule.

I have come up with this so far: `(^K)([0-9a-z]{1,3})` that I believe is correct for the first two rules.

Some correct examples would be:

- Kabc$
- Ka#bc$
- K01#a$
- K#1ab$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^K(?!.*#.*#)(?:#?[0-9a-z]){1,3}#?\$$
```

Or, variations of it:

```
^K(?!(?:.*#){2})(?:#?[0-9a-z]){1,3}#?\$$
^K(?!(?:[^#]*#){2})(?:#?[0-9a-z]){1,3}#?\$$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VfBJAA/2). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `K` - the letter `K`
- `(?!.*#.*#)` / `(?!(?:.*#){2})` / `(?!(?:[^#]*#){2})` - no two `#` are allowed immediately to the right of the current location (this makes sure that if there is a `#`, it only occurs once)
- `(?:#?[0-9a-z]){1,3}` - one, two or three occurrences of

  - `#?` - an optional `#` char
  - `[0-9a-z]` - a lowercase ASCII letter or digit
- `#?` - an optional `#`
- `\$` - a `$` char
- `$` - end of string.